# Recover iCal 10.5 files in 10.6?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, calendar.app

I installed Mac OSX 10.6 and have the old 10.5 on a seperate HDD.  Can I now simply copy the old iCal-Data into the new iCal-installation?

I tried ~/Libarary/Application Support/  but there is no Folder called iCal?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1) Boot into 10.6 and mount the 10.5 HD

2) Open migration assistant

3) Choose to migrate user accounts

4) Tell it to merge/replace the account you want with your old data

That will migrate iCal and all your old settings.

Comment: I can only access the files over ssh and the assistant can't handle that :/

Comment: Is the 10.5 install on another mac with a firewire port if so you can connect the two computers via firewire and boot up the old one in target disk mode by holding the T key at startup.

Comment: no, it's in another PC mounted with ubuntu. I don't have another Mac to fire it up :/

Is there no place where my calendars are saved?

Comment: there is a folder ~/Library/Calendars which you could copy over, I have no idea if copying it over will work.

Answer (score 0):

- In iCal, File | Export your calendar to an iCal data file (.ics).
- Transport it to the other HDD
- In iCal under that OS, import the file.